# Encrypting SOAP messages when using HttpWebRequest and soap message as string

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, encryption, soap

I have implemented a SOAP client based on the code in this thread [Client to send SOAP request and received response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response) however I would now like to extend this to allow us to encrypt the soap message using X509 certs and tripleDes and wondered if there was a starting point. the output payload i am looking for will need to include an xml segment based on schema http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd and probably also include headers, anybody have any links to behind the scenes with soap encryption.

I have found this [Creating Signed SOAP Message as a String with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367034/creating-signed-soap-message-as-a-string-with-c-sharp) aqrticle which seems to be having a similiar issue, where is the theory behind creating the hash values for soap signing.

Comment: I am using one as per in the link:-   http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication 
it might help you in any way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late to my own funeral but it appears the solution is here:

[Creating Signed SOAP Message as a String with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367034/creating-signed-soap-message-as-a-string-with-c-sharp/37981926#37981926)